# Use of undeclared identifier when using struct?

Tags: c, struct

When I try to assign char `string_buffer` in another struct it says

> error use of undeclared identifier

I know that means it I need to declare string buffer in the current `struct` but is there a way without doing this.

```
struct ABC{
char string_buffer[64];
};


struct ABC *DEF(char *name){
name = string_buffer;
};
```

Comment: `string_buffer` is a `char [64]` (an array of 64 `char`s) inside a `struct`. Assume you have more than one `struct` with a member that name (this is allowed). So, how does the compiler know which one you mean?

Answer (score 4):

`string_buffer` is not a normal variable. It is a member variable of a variable of type `struct ABC`. You need to have a variable of type `struct ABC` and then, you need to access it usig the member access operator (`.` or `->`), like

```
struct ABC sample = {0};

.... sample.name   //valid access
```

Also, FWIW, based on your sample code, let me tell you, `string_buffer` is an array. You cannot *assign* the array the way you have shown in the sample snippet. In case you want to copy the content, you need to make use of [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy).

Comment: @iharob That's why I did not use the assignment, I was just trying to show the valid access. :)

Comment: @iharob Updated answer to clarify. :)